# how to initialize in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

I'd like to set up an array of boxes, each with a name and physical dimensions + an uncertainty around them. I've created the following class:

```
struct PhysUnit {
    var Mean: Double = 0.0
    var Sigma: Double = 0.0
}

class Box {
    var Name: String = "null"
    var Width: PhysUnit = (Mean = 0.0 , Sigma = 0.0)
    var Depth: PhysUnit
    var Height: PhysUnit
}

func setupShelves() {
    var A1Box = box()
    A1Box.name = "A1"
    A1Box.Width.Mean = 40.0
    A1Box.Width.Sigma = 0.5
//etc
    shelves.append(A1Box)
return }
```

But how do I initialize the class Box? I've tried many ways, like the example shown, but none work.

Comment: box() doesn't refer to Box(), case matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer:

```
struct PhysUnit {
  var mean: Double = 0.0
  var sigma: Double = 0.0
}

class Box {
  var name: String = "null"
  var width: PhysUnit = PhysUnit()
  var depth: PhysUnit?
  var height: PhysUnit?

  init() {}
}

func setupShelves() {
  var A1Box = Box()
  A1Box.name = "A1"
  A1Box.width.mean = 40.0
  A1Box.width.sigma = 0.5
    ...
  shelves.append(A1Box)
}
```

A couple of things:

- You need to initialize all variables or set them to optional (which
  is what I did)
- Because `PhysUnit` has default values, you don't need
  to set them in `var width` default value.

edit note: I also changed the casing to match Swift best practices

Answer (score 0):

you write box(). Try this: var A1Box = Box()

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in you code.

1. Case is important. Use `Box`, not `box`.
2. Classes must have an initializer (a struct should create one for you)
3. All non-optional properties of a class/struct must be initialized when the instance is initialized

A struct would likely be more appropriate for your model:

```
struct PhysUnit {
    var Mean: Double = 0.0
    var Sigma: Double = 0.0
}

struct Box {
    var Name: String?
    var Width: PhysUnit
    var Depth: PhysUnit
    var Height: PhysUnit
}

func setupShelves() {
    var A1Box = Box(Name: "A1", Width: PhysUnit(Mean: 40, Sigma: 0.5), Depth: PhysUnit(), Height: PhysUnit())
    shelves.append(A1Box)
}
```

But if you insist on using a class you can do this:

```
struct PhysUnit {
    var Mean: Double = 0.0
    var Sigma: Double = 0.0
}

class Box {
    var Name: String?
    var Width: PhysUnit
    var Depth: PhysUnit
    var Height: PhysUnit

    init(Name: String?, Width: PhysUnit, Depth: PhysUnit, Height: PhysUnit) {
        self.Name = Name
        self.Width = Width
        self.Depth = Depth
        self.Height = Height
    }
}

func setupShelves() {
    var A1Box = Box(Name: "A1", Width: PhysUnit(Mean: 40, Sigma: 0.5), Depth: PhysUnit(), Height: PhysUnit())
    shelves.append(A1Box)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go...

```
struct PhysUnit {
    var mean: Double = 0.0
    var sigma: Double = 0.0
}

struct Box {
    var name: String?
    var width = PhysUnit()
    var depth: PhysUnit?
    var height: PhysUnit?
}

func setupShelves() {
    var a1Box = Box()
    a1Box.name = "A1"
    a1Box.width.mean = 40.0
    a1Box.width.sigma = 0.5
}
```

There are more than a few issues with your code here. It may help if you did a Swift tutorial.

This may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ulp1Kimblg0